# Cannot draw map at high scale

Tags: arcmap, scale

In Arcmap 10.8, I am attempting to draw an orthophoto and several polygons at a high scale (not lower than 1:6000). However, Arcmap simply refuses to draw any layers unless I have a spatial resolution as low as app. 1:8000 or lower.

What could the reason be? I have tried the reverse many time (that you need a quite high scale to display certain layers), but never this.

Comment: Does your rasters have pyramids? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-pyramids.htm

Comment: Are your layers set to only be visible at certain scales? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/displaying-layers-at-certain-map-scales.htm

Comment: @BERA All layers should be visible at a scale of 1:6000.

Comment: @ycartwhelen it did not have anything to do with the layer itself since I can display the layer at high scale in other mxd files. 
I managed to find out what the problem was. Apparently the base map layer "World light Grey Reference" was causing all layers not to be drawn at high spatial resolution. Strangely, removing this base map layer removed the problem for all layers.